# почему не срабатывает событие blur в bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, события

**index.html**

```
 <nav  id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked ">
      <li><a class="hide-when-blur" data-toggle="collapse" data-target = "#site-development">Разработка сайтов<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-right navbar-right xs-no-element"></span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    </nav>

<div class="collapse additional-bar" id="site-development">
      <ul class=" relay-style grey-color">
      <li><a href="#">пункт 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">пункт 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">пункт 3</a></li>
    </ul></div>
```

**script.js**

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".hide-when-blur");
for(var key in elements){
    var item = elements[key];
    if(typeof(item)==="object")
        {
        item.addEventListener("blur",function(){
            console.log('blur works!!!');
        })          
    };
}
```

Нужно чтобы при клике на на эл-т с классом hide-when-blur на экране появлялся блок с классом additional-bar(это обеспечивает bootstrap, срабатывает).

А после этого, при нажатии на другой эл-т страницы(потеря фокуса с текущего эл-та) блок additional-bar пропадал.

Так вот событие blur почему-то не срабатывает.
Что нужно сделать?

**P.S. цикл в скрипте нужен чтобы перебрать все эл-ты hide-when-blur**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить атрибут href к ссылке

Вот [ссылка](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html) на список  элементов которые могут словить "фокус". У ссылок (anchor) есть атрибут "href" и методы "focus". ( механика работы скорее всего такая, что без атрибута "href" не можно вызвать "focus/blur").
Вот [ссылка](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/textlevel-semantics.html#the-a-element) по семантике тега "а". В HTML 5 тег а без href валидный но считается как " represents a placeholder " т.е. вы не можете нажать на него (активные элементы меню или хлебные крошки). А если элемент не предполагает нажатие, то и фокус на нем не нужен.

Comment: Помогло, не совсем понятно почему, но сработало, спасибо. Возможно есть ресурс где можно узнать почему так?

Comment: дополнил ответ.